# PHP/CSS Highlight the details for the currently logged in user

Tags: php, css

The code creates a table in which the currently logged in user details are highlighted in blue. This is done using a `$_SESSION['email']` to identify the currently logged in user.

Within the table construction the  elements are declared as a css class `curUser`. This `.curUser` is used in the CSS  file to identify and colour/ highlight the current logged in user.

The problem is that a blank line/row is created after the current user has been selected. I am fairly sure that the problem is the php table creation code.

Can someone please have a look at this and point out the problem, as it is eluding me at present?

**HTML:**

```
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Selections</h1>
    <?php
    require 'configuration.php';
    require 'connectTodb.php';
    ?>


    <table  border="1" id="parent" >
        <tr>
            <th>#</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <?php
            for ($i = 1; $i < 6; $i++) {
                print("<th>Week " . $i . "</th>");
            }
            ?>
        </tr>

        <?php
        $sql = "SELECT selections.week,selections.team,users.email,users.name,selections.outcome FROM users,selections WHERE users.email = selections.email ORDER BY name,week";
        $result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql);
        print mysql_error();
        if (!$result) {
            die('Could not query:' . mysql_error());
        }
        $rowId = 0;
        $rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

        while ($rows != null) {
            print("<tr>");
            $rowId++;
            $name = $rows["name"];
            if ($rows['email'] == $_SESSION['email']) {
                print("<td class=" . $curUser . " type='hidden'   value=" . $rows['email'] . ">" . $rowId . "</td>");
                print("<td class=" . $curUser . "> " . $rows["name"] . "</td>");
                while ($rows != null & $name == $rows['name']) {
                    print("<td class=" . $curUser . "> " . $rows["team"] . "</td>");
                    $rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
                }
                print("</tr>");
            } else {
                print("<td type='hidden'  value=" . $rows['email'] . ">" . $rowId . "</td>");
            }
            print("<td> " . $rows["name"] . "</td>");
            while ($rows != null & $name == $rows['name']) {
                print("<td > " . $rows["team"] . "</td>");
                $rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
            }
            print("</tr>");
        }
        ?>
    </table>

        <?php
        mysqli_close($connection);
        ?>

</body>
```

**CSS**

```
.curUser, #rowId  {
  background-color: lightblue; 
}
```

Comment: I think your else condition does not ended at right place

Answer (score 0):

You are closing the table row twice:

```
                while ($rows != null & $name == $rows['name']) {
                    print("<td class=" . $curUser . "> " . $rows["team"] . "</td>");
                    $rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
                }
                print("</tr>");
```

and here:

```
            while ($rows != null & $name == $rows['name']) {
                print("<td > " . $rows["team"] . "</td>");
                $rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
            }
            print("</tr>");
```

Comment: Ok, that helps, I commented out the first; print("</tr>"); and the blank line/row is gone. Remaining problem is that the name of  the next  registered user is displayed on the same line as the (highlighted) logged in user. The table is made to display ::# Name Week 1 Week 2 Week 3 Week 4 Week 5  {registered user} The registered user name appears in the same row as the logged in user.